# Borrowing images

Tags: support, citation

Can you tell me if it is allowed to borrow a diagram from another post in this site?
Is it necessary to cite both the source and the post from which it was borrowed?

Thanks

Comment: And I diagnose this user76123 was one among the recently removed bunch, discussed [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/what-the-hell-i-just-lost-582-reputation-points). Which means the correct answer below shall never be accepted. Big :(

Comment: @TheDarkSide Since there's no reputation to be gained or lost on meta, it's not a *big* deal that it won't get accepted. Don't sweat it.

Answer (score 4):

*(Answer updated by including Moderator inputs)*

All user contributions on Physics.SE are licensed with the following stipulation, as may be seen from the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) (Section 3), which specify the exact attribution requirements for reusing content outside of the Stack Exchange network:

> user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

The same may also be seen by scrolling to the bottom of this page, which is a mere reminder of the same.

So, attribution is required, i.e. you should cite the source. Once you do that, reusing ("borrowing") images is allowed, which is consistent with this site's [policy on plagiarism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

As an aside, that's also true as a safe, general practice in science.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'd suggest adding a reference to the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) which specify the exact attribution requirements for reusing content outside of the Stack Exchange network (sec 3). _In addition_ to that, for anything posted on _this_ site we have attribution requirements, not as a legal matter, but as part of our [policy on plagiarism](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @DavidZ - Thanks. I have updated the answer including your inputs. But sadly, the OP's gone.